# How to inform TypeScript compiler of required AWS API Gateway query string params

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an API created in AWS API Gateway that consists of a single endpoint called `/callback`. This endpoint was created with a schema the defines the query string params:

```
export const schema = {
  'method.request.querystring.code': true,
  'method.request.querystring.state': true
}
```

AWS will fail the request if it doesn't contain code and state in the query string params.

I'm using TypeScript to define my endpoint handler:

```
import { APIGatewayEvent } from 'aws-lambda';

export const handler = async (event: APIGatewayEvent) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 4));
  const { queryStringParameters } = event;

  // These fields are required by the schema
  const code = queryStringParameters.code;
  const state = queryStringParameters.state;

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: {}
  }
}
```

TypeScript throws a compile error because it doesn't know that code and state are guaranteed to exists on `queryStringParameters`.

So my question is how do I inform typescript that those values are guaranteed to exist?

My current solution is

```
const code = queryStringParameters?.code!;
const state = queryStringParameters?.state!;
```

This works, but I'd prefer it to be properly typed.

Comment: If you don't want the type assertion, you'd have to have some checking the compiler could also use, e.g. https://tsplay.dev/m0V6ow. You _could_ add e.g. `& { queryStringParameters: { code: string; state: string } }` to the parameter type, but then it's possible something else would complain because the caller wasn't guaranteeing that.

Answer (score 0):

The `queryStringParameters` field on the event uses the following interface:

```
export interface APIGatewayProxyEventQueryStringParameters {
    [name: string]: string | undefined;
}
```

By its nature, the keys can be anything you want.

So to take your example:

```
const code = queryStringParameters.code;
const state = queryStringParameters.state;
```

There is nothing wrong with this. The value of `code` or `state` is either a string or undefined, as specificed by the interface.

So any code downstream that uses `code` or `state` must either receive them as optional variables or,

- Add error handling for if they are undefined before they are used
- Or carry on using ! if you have guaranteed they're required in the schema